# Send long JSON string by post in php

Tags: php, json, string

In my windows client, I should sent my data to server with JSON like this:

```
[{"score":"MathJun: 90","shenase":"2981051261"},
{"score":"MathJun: 80","shenase":"2981021192"},
{"score":"ChemJun: 90","shenase":"2981027931"},
{"score":"MathFeb: 90","shenase":"2981060775"},
{"score":"MathJun: 90","shenase":"2981010824"},
{"score":"MathJun: 00","shenase":"2981017039"},
{"score":"ChemJun: 10","shenase":"3120292011"}]
```

And number of JSON blocks in between 1 to 40.
And in my PHP file, in a For loop I insert a record to my database with data of every JSON blocks.
So the JSON string will be so long. One person told to divide it to 5 parts and send it into 5 GET. Does it really effects?

What is the best solution for this job?
Does  then length of JSON string causes problems?
And how should I fix it?
Does executing 40 query in a for loop caused problem?

Comment: this is absolutely not long. Why dividing to 5 parts and not 6 or 7 or 8? That doesent make any senses. Send the whole thing that you have in 1 request.

Comment: Its just 7 blocks, But it may be about 35 blocks with longer value for every "score" like: {"score":"فیزیک ماهانه بهمن 1","shenase":"2981051261"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time JSON will create problem, because it follows proper structure and more over its not stranded if you want to send big data better to use POST.
You can refer the bellow link for more details about GET and POST
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

And coming to your problem
If you avoid multiple req's to the server it will in busy mode. Instead of better make send data in single shot and you can insert data using for loop or else like bellow wise,

insert into table1 (First,Last) values ('Fred','Smith'),
  ('John','Smith'),
  ('Michael','Smith'),
  ('Robert','Smith');

I suggest you, use  POST and send data in single shot, and crate a string

$str="insert into table1 (First,Last) values ('Fred','Smith'),
  ('John','Smith'),
  ('Michael','Smith'),
  ('Robert','Smith')";

like wise and execute the query. It might be fast.

Comment: You mean that just send the query by post?


and then this url dont works for me, How can I fix it? : http://mhrzdev.ir/helliboard/insertScore.php?jsonStr={"score":"فیزیک ماهانه بهمن 1","shenase":"2981051261"}

Comment: Seems to be like that's your server, Before sending data you have to encode and send data to server. Which language your using for developing app in desktop?

So that I'll help you out.

Comment: I use Arabic and Persian. But this URL get me 403 error too. : http://mhrzdev.ir/helliboard/insertScore.php?jsonStr=%22score%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22shenase%22%3A%222981051261%22

Comment: So if I encode my string its will be to long. Eecode it:[{"score":"فیزیک ماهانه بهمن 1","shenase":"2981051261"},{"score":"فیزیک ماهانه بهمن 2","shenase":"2981021192"},{"score":"فیزیک ماهانه بهمن 2","shenase":"2981027931"},{"score":"فیزیک ماهانه بهمن 1","shenase":"2981060775"},{"score":"فیزیک ماهانه بهمن 2","shenase":"2981010824"},{"score":"فیزیک ماهانه بهمن 1","shenase":"2981017039"},{"score":"فیزیک ماهانه بهمن 11","shenase":"3120292011"}]